# 3 word sentence need to reverse only middle word without using any string inbuilt function like charAt(), toCharArray(), split() in java

Tags: reverse

3 word sentence need to reverse only middle word without using any string inbuilt function like charAt(), toCharArray(), split() in java.
Example:
input: "Here we go"
output: "Here ew go"

Answer (score 0):

you can user StringBuilder to convert a string to char[] and bypass toCharArray(), then modify it.
Since technically String constructor is also a inbuilt, you need to print directly from that char[]